# Problems crafting a multi level nested ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm building a calendar app in Rails. 
It's possible to invite people to events.
I'm having difficulties writing a query like `@event.attending_users`.

A calendar Event consists of one or many RecurringEvents. One RecurringEvent has one or many Attendees. The attendees tables is basically a join table that lists which users that's attending a RecurringEvent.

**Event**

```
 21 class Event < ApplicationRecord
 24
 25   has_many :recurring_events, dependent: :destroy
 26   has_many :attendees, through: :reccurring_events
```

**RecurringEvent**

```
 23 class RecurringEvent < ApplicationRecord
 24   has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
 25   has_many :attendees, dependent: :destroy
 26
 27   belongs_to :event
```

**Attendee**

```
 13 class Attendee < ApplicationRecord
 14   belongs_to :recurring_event
 15   belongs_to :user
 16
 17   enum status: %w[unseen seen attending not_attending]
```

**Tests**

```
 23 RSpec.describe Event, type: :model do
 24   before do
 25     @user = Fabricate(:user)
 26     @group = Fabricate(:group)
 27     @event = Fabricate(:event, group: @group, user: @user, recurring: :weekly)
 28   end

 49   describe "Attending" do
 50     before do
 51       @user2 = Fabricate(:user, first_name: "Second User")
 52       @group.add_member(user: @user)
 53       @event.set_user_as_attending_all(@user)
 54     end
```

**app/models/event.rb**

```
 43   def set_user_as_attending_all(user)
 44     return unless user.member_of? group
 45     recurring_events.each do |recurring_event|
 46       recurring_event.attend!(user)
 47     end
 48   end
```

To see which users that is attending on an Event I'm trying to do somethink like this:

```
RecurringEvent.joins(:event).where(event_id: id).joins(:attendees).where(status: "attending")
```

but that fails and I'm not sure why:

```
*** ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" ORDER BY "events"."id" DESC LIMIT $1

nil
*** ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT  "recurring_events".* FROM "recurring_events" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."id" = "recurring_events"."event_id" INNER JOIN "attendees" ON "attendees"."recurring_event_id" = "recurring_events"."id" WHERE "recurring_events"."event_id" = $1 AND "recurring_events"."status" = $2 ORDER BY "recurring_events"."id" ASC LIMIT $3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 1 (as question above),

```
RecurringEvent.joins(:event, :attendees).where('attendees.status = ?', "attending")
```

explanations

- you can joins with one command
- since status is a column in attendees, I include table name before status field

correction 2:

this command below will return attendee records

```
Attendee.joins(recurring_event: :event).where('events.event_id = ? AND attendees.status = ?',453,2)
```

- my suggestion do not use directly number inside where statement, I gave sample above
- the join models now changed with above since attendee access recurring_event, and recurring_event access event (see the difference with my answer above. this meaning access an event depending on recurring_event

Answer 3: this will give users table for specific event

```
User.joins(attendees: [recurring_event: :event]).where('events.event_id = ? AND attendees.status = ?',453,2)
# for unique users
User.joins(attendees: [recurring_event: :event]).where('events.event_id = ? AND attendees.status = ?',453,2).uniq
```

- additional step to my answer 2, this time I traced from user -> attendees -> recurring_event --> event

Comment: Almost there!
`RecurringEvent.joins(:event, :attendees).where('event_id = 453 AND attendees.status = ?', 2)` returns an array with RecurringEvents.
status had to be an int as attendee.status is an enum.
How can we craft the query to return the attending users?

Comment: I see my naming of classes might be a bit confusing. What I need the query to return is a list of Users that are attending an event. :)

Comment: see my answer 3

Comment: Thanks a *LOT* for helping out! :-) <3
The 3 answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: honestly I'm having fun with your problem, challenging and level up for each answer :-)